# Paypal API not working for simple PHP files

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn

this is my code for paypal api. i have both accounts verified, payment is also made... but i am still getting a failure email.. what is the reason i am unable to understand...

```
<?php
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
{
    $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
    $req .= "&$key=$value";
}

    $header .= "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";

    $mode = $paymod_data['MODULE_PAYMENT_PAYPAL_TESTMODE'];

if ($mode == 'test')
{
    $fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);
}
else
{
    $fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);
}

if (!$fp)
{
    // HTTP ERROR
     die ("Error");
}
else 
{   
    fputs ($fp, $header . $req);
    while (!feof($fp)) {
        $res = fgets ($fp, 1024);
        if (strcmp (trim($res), "VERIFIED") == 0) {
            // check the payment_status is Completed
            // check that txn_id has not been previously processed
            // check that receiver_email is your Primary PayPal email
            // check that payment_amount/payment_currency are correct
            // process payment
            echo strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED");
            echo strcmp (trim($res), "INVALID");
            mail("aks0130@gmail.com","sucess","aa gyi mail","From: demo2312@gmail.com");
        }
        else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
            // log for manual investigation
            echo strcmp (trim($res), "INVALID");
            echo strcmp (trim($res), "VERIFIED");
            mail("aks0130@gmail.com","fail","nahi aa gyi mail","From: demo2312@gmail.com");
        }
    }
fclose ($fp);
}
?>
```

i have been trying since 3-4 days to get it done properly, but in vein.. so i am back to stackoverflow

Comment: You are writing WAY too much code. ALL of your socket/http header business can be replaced with just a few lines of curl function calls.

Comment: Marc B, i couldnt find a working curl script even..

Comment: @AnKushSehgal Is this your actual header that you are testing with `"From: demo")`?

Comment: @MarcB can you give me simple working code using curl? or any url that has it?

Comment: @Fred-ii- : that doesn't bother me, email is just to check whether it is a fail or success... although i am always getting failure email..

Comment: @AnKushSehgal Well, right off the bat for me, when I don't see something like `"From: email@example.com")` as an example instead of your own email, and just `"From: demo")` then I start questioning that without knowing if your headers are properly formatted or not.

Comment: @Fred-ii- alright no problem, the issue is how to get into the "VERIFIED" part..

Comment: @AnKushSehgal Two things I spotted is your opening header has a dot in it `$header .= "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";` the first one doesn't need a dot `.=` only subsequent one. 

then this `$header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";` has two sets of `\r\n\r\n` get rid of one of the sets.

Comment: @AnKushSehgal I would also assign a variable to the email address such as `$email_from= "email@example.com";` then use `$headers` as your last entry instead of `"From: demo2312@gmail.com"` for example 
`$header = "From: $email_from" . "\r\n" . "Reply-To: $email_from" . "\r\n" . "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion() . "\r\n" . "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8";` that is probably why it's failing. Tack that on to your other headers.

Comment: @AnKushSehgal Then after that, use `mail("aks0130@gmail.com","fail","nahi aa gyi mail",$header);`

Comment: hey, i read on somewhere on paypal that we need to use \r\n\r\n instead of \r\n as per the changes in their script.. and if i remove one set, i don't get anything.. otherwise i get a mail...

headers not an issue as i am getting a mail... just always the failure one.. even when payments are being received

Comment: @AnKushSehgal Ok so keep that double set of `\r\n` but try my example above. Your headers are not being interpreted, the last entry you have is your email and not `$header` without the double quotes. See the PHP manual on the subject. http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: okay... tried with removing the headers in the mail function.. still doesn't help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After working for days with this thing, i have been able to find a woring Paypal IPN script, i am sharing this script here so that people out there like me, having problems in the script can copy this script from here and paste it in there PHP notify_url page...

```
    // Reading POSTed data directly from $_POST causes serialization issues with array data in the POST.
    // Instead, read raw POST data from the input stream. 
    $raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $raw_post_array = explode('&', $raw_post_data);
    $myPost = array();
    foreach ($raw_post_array as $keyval) {
      $keyval = explode ('=', $keyval);
      if (count($keyval) == 2)
         $myPost[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);
    }
    // read the IPN message sent from PayPal and prepend 'cmd=_notify-validate'
    $req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
    if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc')) {
       $get_magic_quotes_exists = true;
    } 
    foreach ($myPost as $key => $value) {        
       if($get_magic_quotes_exists == true && get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 1) { 
            $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value)); 
       } else {
            $value = urlencode($value);
       }
       $req .= "&$key=$value";
    }


    // STEP 2: POST IPN data back to PayPal to validate

    $ch = curl_init('https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Close'));

    // In wamp-like environments that do not come bundled with root authority certificates,
    // please download 'cacert.pem' from "http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html" and set 
    // the directory path of the certificate as shown below:
    // curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, dirname(__FILE__) . '/cacert.pem');
    if( !($res = curl_exec($ch)) ) {
        // error_log("Got " . curl_error($ch) . " when processing IPN data");
        curl_close($ch);
        exit;
    }
    curl_close($ch);


    // STEP 3: Inspect IPN validation result and act accordingly

    if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0)
    {
        // The IPN is verified, process it:
        // check whether the payment_status is Completed
        // check that txn_id has not been previously processed
        // check that receiver_email is your Primary PayPal email
        // check that payment_amount/payment_currency are correct
        // process the notification

        // assign posted variables to local variables
        $item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
        $item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
        $payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
        $payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
        $payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
        $txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
        $receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
        $payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];

        // IPN message values depend upon the type of notification sent.
        // To loop through the &_POST array and print the NV pairs to the screen:
        foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
        {
          echo $key." = ". $value."<br>";
        }


    }
    else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0)
    {
        // IPN invalid, log for manual investigation


    }
    ?>
```